# God's number for 4x4 cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

The God's number for the 3x3 cube is already established and proven to be 20 moves.

Is there any higher bound computed for the 4x4 fewest move bound, via brute force computation algorithms.

Comment: This is a good question, but I don't think it is a puzzle.

Comment: Anyway this has some lower and upper bounds: https://www.quora.com/What-is-Gods-number-on-a-4x4-Rubiks-cube

Comment: The 4x4 cube is a twisty puzzle. It has a state space which can be discrete. So, twisty puzzles are "puzzles" indeed.

Comment: The answers to that quora query are quite vague. I am sure no one who has answered there has computed and categorised the state space to find a bound. I am asking here as puzzle experts have have a way to deal with this computation complexity problem of finding bounds for 10^40 kind of puzzles.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://cubezzz.dyndns.org/drupal/?q=node%2Fview%2F541

Comment: [3x3x3 Rubik's cube was solved only with a *lot* of CPU time](http://www.cube20.org/) even after a lot of optimization, so I doubt you can find any brute-force results on 4x4x4.

Comment: Nice, this is a 2015 post, there must have been improvements. I do check 4x4 solvers and the bounds that they get, https://cubesolvingprograms.freeforums.net/board/5/4x4x4-solving-programs

Comment: Another useful thread: https://www.speedsolving.com/threads/what-is-gods-number-on-a-4x4-rubiks-cube.35965/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the SS thread. There are knowledgeable speedcubers and mathematicians there. I do read a lot of threads there. But I am looking for methods to build a concrete upper bound proof here, and not just links for some guesses done a few years back.

Comment: We need to find a position that takes a lot of steps to solve. This will give is a lower bound for the gods number. The problem is our solvers are not powerful enough to solve even a single position optimally. In that last link Tomas Rokicki is participating in the discussion - he is the guy who found gods number for 3x3.

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what the "God's number" is, please? This will make the question self-contained, which is a requirement here.

Comment: @abunickabhi, your question was closed as "needing details or clarity" because it cannot be solved without knowledge of what "God's number" is. You can [edit] your question to include all the information necessary to solve. At a minimum this is a full definition of "God's number", and it should also include some explanation of, say, how other "God's numbers" have been found, as you mention the one for 3x3 is known